# Switch() Case: with an already defined constant

Tags: mql4, mql5

The compiler keeps whining about the need of a constant for the `case` type in a `switch(){...}`. But I have ***provided*** a freaking constant. - sorry, <sub>/rant mode off</sub>

Up in my class I have defined the `type` plus the `TYPE_BULLISH` and `TYPE_BEARISH` constants of the `int` types. Then I assigned values:

```
static const int TYPE_BULLISH = 0x001;
static const int TYPE_BEARISH = 0x002;
```

And I assigned the variable **`type`** a value of:

```
type = TYPE_BULLISH;
```

Then in the constructor

```
switch(type) {
    case TYPE_BULLISH: Print("Bullish"); break;
    case TYPE_BEARISH: Print("Bearish"); break;
    default:           Print("Doji");
}
```

Output error:

```
'TYPE_BULLISH' - constant expression required
```

**`Q1:`** Any idea what is going on here?

I mean,
 **`Q2:`** I provided a constant, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `#define` instead (note: No ; at the end of `#define`):

```
#define TYPE_BULLISH    0x001
#define TYPE_BEARISH    0x002
int type = TYPE_BULLISH;

switch(type) {
    case TYPE_BULLISH: Print("Bullish"); break;
    case TYPE_BEARISH: Print("Bearish"); break;
    default:           Print("Doji");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is this global or does it apply to the current class only?

Comment: @Nique, your issue is a syntactic-error. Your code snippets, as you have described above, ignore **`MQL4` scope-of-validity**. `#define` just hides that principal misconcept of a proper structured-software design.

Comment: @Nique: It is Global-scoped. It is quite commonly used. You can see #define being used by many of the built-in MT4 sample/utilities. For example: stderror.mqh, stdliberr.mqh, winuser32.mqh, etc. #define is being used all the time.

Answer (score 1):

### `A2:` No, you have not provided a constant.
`A1:` Your MQL4 code is syntactically wrong and cannot get compiled.

---

While @JosephLee has provided a error-avoiding substitute, the problem is hidden in a way, `MQL4`-code retains a **scope-of-validity**

Your `class`-level designations cease to exist outside the container, where these have been declared / initialised.

Your code, outside of such container ( typically the inner-most surrounding `{ ... }`-code block / hierarchy-level, where such a declaration took place ) simply cannot get compiled, as the compiler obeys the rules of scope-of-validity during the source-code parsing.

```
Q.E.D.
```

One may use "globally"-visible variables in case of a need for such centrally managed predefined constants.

Beware, that `#include`, `#import`, `#property library` and `#export` introduce more havoc into this circus.

> <sub>You were warned, at least...</sub>

---

**`A use of a utility-function`**:

[image]

---

**`Example code how to use it from one library project`**:

[image]

Comment: So basically, the Switch() case is useless unless you hardcode the to be matches values over and over again all over the place? Seems weird :).

Comment: @Nique btw, if you need not some artificial magic with a fixed memory location data-mapper, bypassing a stack-allocation mechanics, for some pretty nasty things, a **`static const int ... `** has no reason for storing a value. ( `#define` is a pre-compiler parsing directive, so actually no scope-checking takes place, just a lexer sequential code-stream analysis, so be carefull just about overlapping values & a global Project unique-error-number catalogue maintenance as in example --  `#define anotherErrorNUMBER  HAUSNUMERO + 161` ( a trick seen from Pieter Hintjens' code foundry :o) ).

Comment: Hmm #define is not the way to go i think. I want to keep the stuff inside the class scope. No need for global.

Comment: @Nique just for clarity, as you 've asked in first comment, **`#define <aLiteralSymbol> <aValue>`** are pre-processor directives and are thus lexically interpreted for the whole rest of the source-code file, ignoring any code-unit hierarchy & encapsulation, this a simple `#include ...` may help you in the very same manner as the **`.h`** header files do in **`C`**.